# Publishing problem with gazebo using trajectory_msgs

Tags: ros, gazebo, trajectory-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm working on arm robotic, first, i wrote a physical model of the arm with a URDF files. This model work with Rviz and Gazebo. Moreover, i created a controllers.yaml file (for controls all robot's joints) and when I use the command : `rostopic pub /arm_controller/command trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory '{joint_names: ["hip","shoulder","elbow","wrist"], points: [{positions:[0.1,-0.5,0.5,0.75], time_from_start: [1.0,0.0]}]}' -1` both models (on rivz and gazebo) move simultaneously.

But now, I want to create a .cpp file for the arm to move independently by using trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory. Here's my cpp file :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h>

ros::Publisher arm_pub;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
ros::init(argc, argv, "state_publisher");
ros::NodeHandle n;
arm_pub = n.advertise<trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory>("/arm_controller/command",1);

trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory traj;

traj.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
traj.header.frame_id = "base_link";
traj.joint_names.resize(4);
traj.points.resize(4);

traj.joint_names[0] ="hip";
traj.joint_names[1] ="shoulder";
traj.joint_names[2] ="elbow";
traj.joint_names[3] ="wrist";

while(ros::ok()){
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
      int j = i%3;
      trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint points_n;
      points_n.positions.push_back(j+0.1);
      points_n.positions.push_back(j+0.3);
      points_n.positions.push_back(j+0.3);
      points_n.positions.push_back(j);
      traj.points.push_back(points_n);
      traj.points[i].time_from_start = ros::Duration(1.0,0.0);
   }

  arm_pub.publish(traj);
  ros::spinOnce();
 }

return 0;
}
```

When i launch my file.launch and I rosrun my cpp file, both are connected on rqt_graph.
But immediately, i have an error (on launch terminal) :

> [ERROR] [1497596211.214814221, 9.889000000]: Trajectory message contains waypoints that are not strictly increasing in time.

Effectively, when i use the command `rostopic echo /arm_controller/command`, i have :

```
`positions: [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0]
 velocities: []
 accelerations: []
 effort: []
 time_from_start: 
  secs: 0
  nsecs: 0`
```

The time_from_start is always 0. So, I think i've a problem in my code but i don't know where.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264013/publishing-problem-with-gazebo-using-trajectory_msgs/) by [w.fradin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29616/w.fradin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-06-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-16**:
Not a complete answer, but: know that `time_from_start` does not encode segment length directly, but is actually the *point in time* at which that `TrajectoryPoint` should be executed. Setting them all to `1.0` is not going to work, as all traj pts will then effectively 'overlap' in time.

**Comment by [w.fradin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29616/w.fradin/) on 2017-06-16**:
I understood that each trajectory point's time_from_start must be greater than the last. But I tried to increase this time but i have the same error. The problem is only in my code or it could come from my launch files?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-17**:
As I wrote, it was just a comment, not an answer to your problem. I just wanted to make you aware that your example code seems to be setting `time_from_start` to incorrect values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved my problem. Here is my first example that working and i explain it after :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h>
#include "ros/time.h"

ros::Publisher arm_pub;

int setValeurPoint(trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory* trajectoire,int pos_tab, int val);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "state_publisher");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    arm_pub = n.advertise<trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory>("/arm_controller/command",1);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory traj;
    trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectoryPoint points_n;

    traj.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    traj.joint_names.resize(4);
    traj.points.resize(1);

    traj.points[0].positions.resize(4);

    traj.joint_names[0] ="hip";
    traj.joint_names[1] ="shoulder";
    traj.joint_names[2] ="elbow";
    traj.joint_names[3] ="wrist";

    int i(1);

    while(ros::ok()) {

        traj.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                setValeurPoint(&traj,j,i);
        }

        traj.points[0].time_from_start = ros::Duration(1);

        arm_pub.publish(traj);
        ros::spinOnce();

        loop_rate.sleep();
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int setValeurPoint(trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory* trajectoire,int pos_tab, int val){
    trajectoire->points[0].positions[pos_tab] = val;
    return 0;
}
```

If you compare the two codes, I initialized (in the first one) "traj.points.resize()" to 4. It was a mistake because all points are connected to each other with 1 parent or 1 child. So, i've only 1 way-points (if i've 2 robot arm, i will have had 2 way-points...) and this way-points is defined by 4 positions (hip,shoulder,elbow,wrist). Moreover, i had forgotten to initialize and resize "traj.points[0].positions" to 4 (numbers of joints). Finally, "time_from_start = ros::Duration(1)" doesn't need to be incremented, as I read it, because it's the speed of the movement of the robot arm.

---

Originally posted by [w.fradin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29616/w.fradin/) with karma: 38 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-01-18**:
Hi, did you manage to move the model? Is it posible you can contact me trough my e-mail, because I have some doubts about a similar thing. juantelo95@gmail.com

**Comment by [HanYangRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/38773/hanyangrobotics/) on 2018-11-29**:
Hi I am curious as to which tutorial you are viewing and how you have written the publisher node. Can you tell me?

**Comment by [RobDawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/55822/robdawson/) on 2020-06-16**:
I realise this is a late reply, from the look of the code however, the tutorial is the Cougarbot from Programming Robots with ROS.